# Groups with more than half elements of order 2

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In Dihedral groups, at least half elements are of order two.

**Question:** If a (non-abelian) finite group has at least half elements order two, then what can be said about the group?

Comment: One may consider cases: "when $G$ has exactly half elements of order 2" and "when $G$ has more than half elements of order 2".

Comment: This might be related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40028

Comment: @JimmyK4542: Thanks for good suggestion.